# ''Access to restricted URI denied'" error when trying to use ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I'm trying to use ng-include for recursive templates in my html. I first tried it with jsfiddle and it works. Here is URL http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/3115/ .
However when i try to do same thing locally. I get this error:

```
Error: Access to restricted URI denied
createHttpBackend/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:10765:1
sendReq@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:10558:1
$http/serverRequest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:10268:16
processQueue@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:14792:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:14808:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:16052:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:15870:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:16160:13
bootstrapApply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:1679:9
invoke@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4523:14
```

Here is my complete source code file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module("Application", []).
controller("TreeController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.links = [{
    "id": 1,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "adjacentLists": [{
      "id": 2,
      "fc": "FC_1",
      "adjacentLists": [{
        "id": 3,
        "fc": "FC_1",
        "adjacentLists": [{
          "id": 7,
          "fc": "FC_1",
          "speedLimit": 55
        }, {
          "id": 6,
          "fc": "FC_1",
          "speedLimit": 60
        }, {
          "id": 8,
          "fc": "FC_1",
          "speedLimit": 0
        }],
        "speedLimit": 0
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "fc": "FC_1",
        "speedLimit": 0
      }, {
        "id": 5,
        "fc": "FC_2",
        "adjacentLists": [{
          "id": 9,
          "fc": "FC_3",
          "speedLimit": 0,
          "query": {
            "question": "Link 9 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
            "response": false
          }
        }, {
          "id": 11,
          "fc": "FC_3",
          "speedLimit": 0,
          "query": {
            "question": "Link 11 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
            "response": false
          }
        }],
        "speedLimit": 0,
        "query": {
          "question": "Link 5 has differnet function class of FC_2 instead of FC_1 of source link 2. Do you want to continue?",
          "response": false
        }
      }],
      "speedLimit": 0
    }],
    "speedLimit": 50
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "adjacentLists": [{
      "id": 3,
      "fc": "FC_1",
      "adjacentLists": [{
        "id": 7,
        "fc": "FC_1",
        "speedLimit": 55
      }, {
        "id": 6,
        "fc": "FC_1",
        "speedLimit": 60
      }, {
        "id": 8,
        "fc": "FC_1",
        "speedLimit": 0
      }],
      "speedLimit": 0
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "fc": "FC_1",
      "speedLimit": 0
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "fc": "FC_2",
      "adjacentLists": [{
        "id": 9,
        "fc": "FC_3",
        "speedLimit": 0,
        "query": {
          "question": "Link 9 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
          "response": false
        }
      }, {
        "id": 11,
        "fc": "FC_3",
        "speedLimit": 0,
        "query": {
          "question": "Link 11 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
          "response": false
        }
      }],
      "speedLimit": 0,
      "query": {
        "question": "Link 5 has differnet function class of FC_2 instead of FC_1 of source link 2. Do you want to continue?",
        "response": false
      }
    }],
    "speedLimit": 0
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "adjacentLists": [{
      "id": 7,
      "fc": "FC_1",
      "speedLimit": 55
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "fc": "FC_1",
      "speedLimit": 60
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "fc": "FC_1",
      "speedLimit": 0
    }],
    "speedLimit": 0
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "speedLimit": 0
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "fc": "FC_2",
    "adjacentLists": [{
      "id": 9,
      "fc": "FC_3",
      "speedLimit": 0,
      "query": {
        "question": "Link 9 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
        "response": false
      }
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "fc": "FC_3",
      "speedLimit": 0,
      "query": {
        "question": "Link 11 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
        "response": false
      }
    }],
    "speedLimit": 0,
    "query": {
      "question": "Link 5 has differnet function class of FC_2 instead of FC_1 of source link 2. Do you want to continue?",
      "response": false
    }
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "speedLimit": 60
  }, {
    "id": 7,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "speedLimit": 55
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "speedLimit": 0
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "fc": "FC_1",
    "adjacentLists": [{
      "id": 9,
      "fc": "FC_3",
      "speedLimit": 0,
      "query": {
        "question": "Link 9 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
        "response": false
      }
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "fc": "FC_3",
      "speedLimit": 0,
      "query": {
        "question": "Link 11 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
        "response": false
      }
    }],
    "speedLimit": 0
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "fc": "FC_3",
    "speedLimit": 0,
    "query": {
      "question": "Link 9 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
      "response": false
    }
  }, {
    "id": 11,
    "fc": "FC_3",
    "speedLimit": 0,
    "query": {
      "question": "Link 11 has differnet function class of FC_3 instead of FC_2 of source link 5. Do you want to continue?",
      "response": false
    }
  }];
  $scope.link = $scope.links[0];

}]);

</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_item_renderer.html">
  Processing Link {{link.id}}</br>
  <span ng-if="link.query">
    {{link.query.question}}
    </span>
  <span ng-if="link.adjacentLists.length>0">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="link in link.adjacentLists" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
    </span>
</script>


<body>
<ul ng-app="Application" ng-controller="TreeController">
  <span ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'"></span>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running your app on some webserver locally? Sounds like you are trying to access templates via `file://` protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are probably opening the html file on the `file://` protocol. Try serving it locally using a simple http server (e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory the file is in if you have Python installed).

According to [the Angular docs for `ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

> By default, the template URL is restricted to the same domain and protocol as the application document. This is done by calling $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl on it. To load templates from other domains or protocols you may either whitelist them or wrap them as trusted values. Refer to Angular's Strict Contextual Escaping.
>
> In addition, the browser's Same Origin Policy and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy may further restrict whether the template is successfully loaded. **For example, ngInclude won't work for cross-domain requests on all browsers and for file:// access on some browsers.** *[emphasis mine]*

P.S.: Running your code served from a local server worked. :)

Comment: Voting up, I was typing my comment in the same time :)